# Web para comprobar el estado de un servidor

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

¡Hola! Estoy con lo siguiente HTML-JS-PHP, intentado hacer una web que compruebe una URL por un PUERTO (e.j.: ejemplo.com:443) y que muestre por pantalla si el servicio es accesible (PASS) o no (FAIL).

He hecho lo siguiente:

Código HTML + SCRIPT JS: (index .html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">
            
                <!-- Table -->
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    <table class="alt">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Web</td>
                                <td>Estado de la página web.</td>
                                <td><span data-check="ejemplo.com:443"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Servidor de Minecraft</td>
                                <td>Estado del servidor de Minecraft.</td>
                                <td><span data-check="ejemplo.com:25565"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
 
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>


        <!-- Script -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('[data-check]').each(function(index, item) { 
                setTimeout(function(){
                        $i = $(item);
                        var url = $i.data('check');
                        console.log(url);
                        $i.html('<img src="loading.gif" style="width:16px;">');
                        var check = [B]QUIERO IGUALAR ESTA VARIABLE A UN BOOL QUE DEVUELVA EL PHP[/B];
                        console.log(check);
                        if(check == true){
                            $i.html('PASS');
                            console.log('PASS');
                        } else{
                            $i.html('FAIL');
                            console.log('FAIL');
                        }
                }, index);
              });
            });
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código PHP: (status .php)

```
<?php

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    list($dominio, $puerto) = explode(":", $url);

    $resultado = status($dominio, $puerto);

    function status($dominio, $puerto){
            $starttime = microtime(true);
            $file      = @fsockopen ($dominio, $puerto, $errno, $errstr, 10);
            $stoptime  = microtime(true);
            $status    = 0;
        
            if (!$file){    
                $status = -1;  // Sitio caído
            } else {
                fclose($file);
                $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
                $status = floor($status);
            }
            
            if ($status == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            
    }

?>
```

Sobre todo lo que me interesa saber es:
1.-Si estoy pasando bien los datos del HTML al PHP para que haga las comprobaciones correctas.
2.-Cómo hacer que el script de JS sepa si el código PHP ha devuelto "true" o "false" ó "0" o "-1", me da igual.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El PHP debería devolver el valor de $resultado, o en su caso escribirlo con un echo.  Aquí necesitarías usar ajax para que el JavaScript llame al PHP. Hay muchos ejemplos aquí en so. Echa un vistazo

Comment: Yo creo que lo que deberías chequear es los headers que devuelve ese servidor como respuesta a la petición de ese recurso o url, y buscar un código de estado 200 dentro de esa cabecera.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que asegurarte de que tu archivo PHP retorne un objecto JSON. Para ello, al final de toda tu lógica agregas un `echo json_encode`

```php
<?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    list($dominio, $puerto) = explode(":", $url);

    $resultado = status($dominio, $puerto);

    function status($dominio, $puerto){
        $starttime = microtime(true);
        $file      = @fsockopen ($dominio, $puerto, $errno, $errstr, 10);
        $stoptime  = microtime(true);
        $status    = 0;

        if (!$file){
            $status = -1;  // Sitio caído
        } else {
           fclose($file);
            $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
            $status = floor($status);
        }

        if ($status == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    # Devuelve uon objeto de la forma {status: boolean} al cliente
    echo json_encode(array("status" => $resultado));
?>
```

Luego en tu script de JavaScript debes hacer una petición POST a tu archivo PHP utilizando ajax.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-check]').each(function(index, item) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $i = $(item);
      var url = $i.data('check');
      console.log(url);
      $i.html('<img src="loading.gif" style="width:16px;">');
      // Petición ajax
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ubicacion-de-tu-archivo.php',
        data: {url},
        success: function(response) {
          // En caso de obtener una respuesta (el echo json_encode), accedes a la propiedad status
          var check = response.status;
          // Y procedes con la validación de este dato para lograr tu cometido
          if(check){
            $i.html('PASS');
            console.log('PASS');
          } else{
              $i.html('FAIL');
              console.log('FAIL');
          }
        }
      });
    }, index);
  });
});
```

Obviamente esto es una implementación sencilla, tú deberás asegurarte de manejar errores y de cómo ejecutar la función según tus necesidades.

Comment: Parece bien encaminada la respuesta, pero en _PHP_ dejaste un par de `return` que impiden la salida en formato _JSON_

Comment: Los return que mencionas se encuentran dentro de la función `status` y en cualquiera de ambos casos el resultado de ese return es asignado a la variable `$resultado` que es la que hace la llamada a dicha función. Por lo que no habría inconveniente en imprimir posteriormente el array codificado puesto que en el flujo solo se llama una vez a la función

Comment: Cierto, no me di cuenta que estaba en una función. Me disculpo. En unas horas (o mañana) voy a borrar mis comentarios para no afectar la publicación.